# Angular routing from table row to item

Tags: angularjs, routes

I have a page containing a table of Listings (aka Products). I need to add an **Edit Listing** button to each row, that will go to a new page where I can edit a single Listing(Product).

So: **Listings > Edit a Listing**.

The HTML is just templates - HTML snippet in the content area of my SPA. (I mention this because I have to make sure my pages are linked to their correct controllers - my snippets/templates do not have ng-controller= on them - that's higher up the page.)

Anyway, this is what I'm trying to do to route Listings to Edit Listing:

listings.html:

```
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-checkable order-column"
           id="listings-table"
           datatable="ng"
           dt-options="listingVm.dtOptions"
           dt-column-defs="listingVm.dtColumnDefs">
        <tr ng-repeat="listing in listingVm.listings">
            <td>{{ listing.Title }}</td>
            <td>{{ listing.Description }}</td>
    <!-- my addition: -->
            <td><a ng-click="listingVm.editListing(listing.Id)"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

listingsController.js:

```
    vm.editListing = function (listingId) {
    // I'll figure out how to get the data later
    //$http.get('/api/Listing/').then(function (response) {
    //  console.log(response);
    $location.path('/editlisting/' + listingId);
    //}, function (response) {
    //});

    }
```

router.js:

```
            .state('layout.listing', {
                url: '/listing',
                templateUrl: '/Content/js/apps/store/views/listing.html',
                controller: 'listingController',
                controllerAs: 'listingVm',
                data: { pageTitle: 'Listings' }
            })
    // I added this:
            .state('layout.editlisting', {
                url: '/editlisting/:id',
                templateUrl: '/Content/js/apps/store/views/edit_listing.html',
                controller: 'editListingController',
                controllerAs: 'listingVm',
                data: { pageTitle: 'Edit Listing' }
            })
```

I uh ... I'm stuck. I don't really know how this should work.

What it *does* is immediately redirect to my default dashboard page: /#/dashboard, which is what I'd expect it to do if it couldn't find a page by that name. (there *is* no error, just the reroute to default)

It looks like I might be using a mangling of two ways of routing?

eg. if I've got a state in my router, can I just do this:

```
<a ui-sref="layout.editlisting">
```

Comment: try $location.url('/editlisting/' + listingId);

Comment: Thx. It seems my problem wasn't with the router after all, it was with that path.

Comment: Another quick question: how do I retrieve the listingId one I'm on editListing page? Do I pull it from the URL querystring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's make that a clean answer instead of a comment.

`$location.path` will send an URL without the parameters.

```
$location.url('/editlisting/' + listingId);
```

Should work as intented.

To retrieve the parameter inside the receiving controller you first have to inject $stateParams which contains the named parameters from the request:

```
.controller('YourCtrl', ['$stateParams', function($stateParams) {
    this.listingId = $stateParams.listingId;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. **$stateParams** is the answer. I was poring over $route.